# Access obj in for loop

Tags: javascript

```js
objVar = "one";
varID = ["Result1", "Result2"];
var one = {
  Result1: 5,
  Result2: 100
}

for (i = 0; i < varID.length; i++) {
  textID = '#' + varID[i];
  document.querySelector(textID).innerHTML = "??";
}
```

```html
<div id="Result1"></div>
<div id="Result2"></div>
```

In place ofthe question marks (`??`), I need to get the value of `objVar[i]`. Is this possible directly (i.e., without `a = eval(objVar); a[varID[i]]`)?

Comment: `one[ varID[i] ]`.

Comment: actually, objVar can change. depending upon that, object needs to access.

Comment: if varID is always the 2 object keys you can use Object.keys(one) which will return an array of all the keys

Comment: I updated the question for better understanding.

Comment: Very difficult to chose one accepted ans. Everyone gave same and right ans. Also, my fault is question was not clear in the beginning. #what2do?

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]** : As you said that `objVar` can also change so you can make `one` object as a property of a parent object and access it. If not then you can make it global and use  it as a property of `window` object though I don't recommend creating global variable.

You can access the property on object `one` by bracket notation like this:

```
var masterObj = {
 one : {
  Result1: 5,
  Result2: 100
 },
 two: : {
  Result1: 5,
  Result2: 100
 },
}


document.querySelector(textID).innerHTML = masterObj[objVar][varID[i]];
```

OR

```
document.querySelector(textID).innerHTML = window[objVar][varID[i]];//for global variable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 window[objVar][ varID[i] ]
```

And you should probably choose another datastructure:

```
var lookup = {
 one: {
  Result1: 5,
  Result2: 100
 }
};
```

...cause you should try not to use `window` for anything.

Comment: "should probably choose another datastructure", can you explain why and what? I just started learning from w3.

Comment: @Mr.EU sure, and please leave w3 schools and got to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) its more accurate

Comment: I kept `one`, `two` in different js file because they are large. and the js file loads depending upon `objVar` which changes dynamically (if required). In any case, if user wants to access these files, they easily can. What happens if I use `window`?

Answer (score 1):

You can call this :

```
... = one[varID[i]];
```

*actually, objVar can change. depending upon that, object needs to access.*

Based on this comment:

```
... = window[objVar][varID[i]]
```

```js
objVar = "one";
varID = ["Result1", "Result2"];
var one = {
  Result1: 5,
  Result2: 100
}

for (i = 0; i < varID.length; i++) {
  textID = '#' + varID[i];
  document.querySelector(textID).innerHTML = window[objVar][varID[i]];
}
```

```html
<div id="Result1"></div>
<div id="Result2"></div>
```

And other examples can be using `Object.keys()`:

```js
objVar = "one";

var one = {
  Result1: 5,
  Result2: 100
}

Object.keys(window[objVar]).forEach(
     res => document.querySelector('#'+res).innerHTML = one[res]
)
```

```html
<div id="Result1"></div>
<div id="Result2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use console.log for testing, you can use document.querySelector.

```
var objVar = {

    one: {
        Result1: 5,
        Result2: 100
    },

    two: {
        Result3: 12,
        Result4: 13
    }

};

var varID = ["Result1", "Result2"];
var textID;

//chose object from user or any way you want ...
var customObject = "one";


for (let i = 0; i < varID.length; i++) {
    textID = '#' + varID[i];
    console.log(objVar[customObject][varID[i]]);
}
```